# how to skip this dialog use preseed?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-14.04

I put these in my preseed script but still seeing this dialog. How can i disable this dialog?

```
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string us
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

finally figured out myself, the place to add the flag(keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us) is in kernal parameter not in preseed file

```
label scilent
  menu label ^Silent Install
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append  keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us console-setup/ask_detect=false preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed/my.cfg debian-installer/locale=en_US console-setup/layoutcode=us initrd=/install/initrd.gz ramdisk_size=16384 root=/dev/ram rw quiet --
```